# Understanding a job posting "Если у вас есть суперсила, расскажите о ней в отклике."

Tags: перевод

> От нас:
>
> Интересная исследовательская работа, возможность создавать новые
> нестандартные решения в области работы с данными
>
> Высокая заработная плата - фикс + бонусы (обсуждается индивидуально с
> успешными кандидатами).
>
> Оформление, условия работы, социальный пакет по ТК РФ.
>
> В сопроводительном письме расскажите, пожалуйста, немного о себе и
> своем опыте, почему вы хотите работать с нами.
>
> P.S.: Если у вас есть суперсила, расскажите о ней в отклике.

What do they mean by "суперсила"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Суперсила" means [superpower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpower_(ability)), i.e. some supernatural force, like one of a superhero.

From [wikipedia on superhero](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9):

> Супергерóй (англ. Superhero) — персонаж, наделённый неординарными физическими способностями («**суперсилой**»), которые он направляет на свершение подвигов во имя общего блага

(emphasis mine).

---

In this particular job posting, the sentence about "суперсила" is a joke, probably an attempt to make a posting sound less formal, and stand out.

At the same time, it can be seen as an invitation to share more details about yourself that usually fall out of a typical CV, or to make your CV a bit less formal and add some matching joke (not that I recommend it), or if you indeed have some unusual ability or skill, to share it, even if it is not relevant to the job, etc.